# Spring INT property for annotation int parameter for spring application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, parameter-passing

I have spring-boot application. application.xml and some annotated methods.
In case **string** properties from application.xml is OK. For example:

```
@KafkaListener(id = "${app.kafka.group}", topics = {"${app.kafka.topic}"}, containerFactory = "singleFactoryCap", autoStartup = "true")
    public void consume(Event event) throws ParseException { ...
```

But how to put **INTEGER** property from application.xml into an annotation parameter of method?

```
@Scheduled(initialDelay = ???"${app.config.initialDelay:5000}"???, fixedDelay = ???"${app.config.fixedDelay:5000}"???)
    public void loadEvents() {
```

Answer (score 1):

The [@Scheduled](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) annotation takes long properties `initialDelay`, `fixedRate` and `fixedDelay` if you want to hard-code the values but the annotation also provides the properties `initialDelayString`, `fixedRateString` and `fixedDelayString` that you can use as an alternative if you want to configure the behaviour using external configuration properties.

Comment: but how that could be added in the code? initialDelay = #{...} is not gonna be compiled.

Comment: Ah sorry, I did not properly interpret the question. I adjusted my answer